# How to prevent "pandas.read_csv" convert index column to float with arg 'dtype=np.float32'?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, indexing, type-conversion

I have a CSV file to be read by pandas, and it has the form as following:

```
name,   quart2c,    p_rat,  other_col
avg,    1,          2,      3
std,    1,          2,      3
```

I want to `pandas.read_csv()` guarantee that all cells have the type of float32, except the first column('name') because that is the index column.

Hence I pass two args to it like this:

```
pandas.read_csv(file_path, index_col=0, dtype=np.float32)

# or like this, both failed
pandas.read_csv(file_path, index_col='name', dtype=np.float32)
```

But pandas still tries to convert the first column to float, and raises a exception:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'avg'

What I want:

1. The CSV file is made by another program coded by myself. If the structure is wrong, I can adjust it easily.
2. I want to always specify the arg `dtype=np.float32`, so as to check whether there are any error values. I don't want the values be interpreted to integer type also.
3. The index column "name" should be reserved as `index_col`, since it will be used later. This column should **NOT** be cut off anyway.

How should I get it?

Comment: `dtype=dict.fromkeys(['quart2c', 'p_rat', 'other_col'], float)`

Comment: My csv file has a lot of columns, while I list here 4 ones. And the column names may change in the future. Thank you anyway!

Comment: What about `pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col='name').astype(float)`?

Comment: @JoshFriedlander I tried your solution, and I think it is the best for my problem.  Would you please post a answer ? Maybe it can help the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best is to first read in the csv with default args, giving index col, and then convert the entire df (which will not affect the index):

```
pd.read_csv(file_path, index_col='name').astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way with `dtype` and `converters`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype = 'float32', converters = {'name': str},index_col='name')  
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
         quart2c      p_rat    other_col
name                                    
avg          1.0        2.0          3.0
std          1.0        2.0          3.0
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, but I got a warnning:"ParserWarning: Both a converter and dtype were specified for column name - only the converter will be used..."   It looks like the dtype takes no effect when 'converters' exists?

Comment: Is there a way I can clear this warning?

Comment: From the docs: "If converters are specified, they will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion."